# In asp.net-mvc, Is it wrong to move my "EditViewModel" classes outside my MVC web project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have an asp.net-mvc site that pretty much is a CRUD app but I also do some adds & updates outside the webview (upload from spreadsheets, etc).  [Based on this article](http://paulstovell.com/blog/clean-aspnet-mvc-controllers), I am trying to get as much of the logic outside the MVC project into a seperate shared project so i can reuse the same code in all scenarios and I am trying to isolate and seperate my "read" viewModels that are binding to UIs for display from the "edit" viewModels that represent what is being posted to the server on a form post.

I have a number of projects in the solution (domainobjects, importexport,etc) that are shared with other solution plus the MVC project has the following directories in the MVC project

- Controllers
- Views
- ViewModels
- Scripts
- EditViewModels

My ViewModels folder represents the objects that I am binding to my views (a container object that usually includes:

- A domain object and
- A bunch of IEnumerable of SelectListItem to populate UI dropdowns, etc

something like this:

```
 public class OrderViewModel
 {
       public Order MyOrder {get;set;}
       public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OrderTypes {get;set;}
       public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Sizes {get;set;}
 }
```

My EditViewModels folder represents the objects that i am posting from forms to the server so they are usually simpler flat objects with just primatives that i then populate a domain object with before adding or updating my database like this:

```
public class OrderEditViewModel
{
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public int OrderTypeId {get;set;}
      public int SizeId {get;set;}
}
```

My main question is when i have a method in my Controller class that usually looks like this (simplified):

```
  public ActionResult Update(OrderEditViewModel order)
  {
         var existingOrder = _repository.GetOrder(order.Id);
         existingOrder.Name = order.Name;
         existingOrder.Size = _repository.GetSize(order.SizeId);
         existingOrder.Price = order.Price;
         _repository.Save(existingOrder);
         return Json( Result = "Success");
  }
```

I am trying to figure out how to get as much code as possible outside the MVC project but that forces me to move all of my classes in the EditViewModel outside of the MVC project so those objects can be reused.

Does anyone see anything wrong with having these "Post" data structure classed outside the MVC projecdt.  Given its a "viewmodel" class it feels wrong to move it away from the view but I don't see any other way to share this code outside of the MVC project.   Maybe the "viewModel" name here is just wrong possibly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your View Models are specific to your views, and should not be relevant to anything else.  They contain things which nothing else should care about, such as your select lists.  As such, they should stay in your UI.

The article appears to me to be creating a situation in which the business logic depends on the UI (or at least the UI Model.. ie View Model), and I think that is the wrong approach.  The UI should be able to consume the business logic without the business logic being aware what the UI is.  It could be a web site, a fat client, a mobile client, a web service, etc...  By making this logic depend on your view models, you now are making any future services that are not web based depend on those.

This is, however, a simple CRUD app, and in simple CRUD apps you can often take a lot of shortcuts because it's just not worth the extra engineering effort.  I wouldn't normally pass a domain object to the view directly in the View Model.  But in this case it's probably the best choice.

If you want to do it "right", however, then you need to create more separation of concerns.  Your domain and ui layers need more separation.  You create separate view and domain models, and then map between them.  This prevents the business layer from knowing anything about the UI.

I would probably create a service layer that handles your logic.  For instance:

```
_orderService.UpdateOrder(order.Id, order.Name, order.Price);
```

Comment: i tend to agree with you on this . .

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i make a difference between read(view-)models and write-models.

Read models are very specific to the view, they can contain select lists and formatted and localized content. You should not move this models outside of your ui-project. Of course you can make a separate assembly with your models, or you can make one assembly per module, but you should never consume these models from your domain layer.

Write models - in my opinion - are not that specific to your UI. Instead they represent the data that is required by the command (e.g. SaveUserCommand). They can contain validation attributes, so your domain layer can validate them easily and they can be shared by domain layer and UI. In my project I have one class per command (e.g. SaveUserCommand, EditUserCommand, DeleteUserCommand) and related models (SaveUserModel, EditUserModel). Somebody will comment, that the they also contain some UI-specific code (e.g. the IClientValidateable itnerface for attributes or the attributes itself) and at least the IClientValidateable interface is a problem that I am willing to ignore to reduce the number of models. My experience with this approach (I also tried others) shows, that these models are very easy and it very easy to bind to these models.

Sometimes you will also have the problem, that you want to show some additional information in the edit-view. Instead of adding all this information to the viewbag, I will have another model, for example:

```
 class UserEditModel 
 {
     string Password;
 }

 UserEditViewModel
 {
     DateTime Modified;

     UserEditModel Edit;
 }
```

So my advice:

1. Create write-models that have all the data and validation logic that is specific to your use cases.
2. Create view models that contain all data you want to display and try not to use the ViewBag.
3. If you have a form, add the write-model to your view model. The write-model has all the data that will be sent back to your server via POST and then directly to your domain layer.

Answer (score 1):

I use four "layers" in two assemblies

{application}.app assembly with three namespaces, just a regular class library project.

1) {application}.model for domain model

2) {application}.data for data using repository pattern

3) {application}.services for all business logic

{application}.WebUI assembly for the UI, this is the MVC project

Controllers only call services and services get and update data through the repositories.

There is an services API for every operation your app has to do, i.e.

OrderServices.Update (existingOrder)

OrderServices.Approve (existingOrder)

Services layer only know domain models, and controllers just assemble the viewmodels, using the domain models gotten from services, to send them to the views and prepare the domain models using the viewmodels gotten from the views to send them to the appropiate service.

This way you can eventually create an {application}.WebAPI or whatever that uses the same {application}.app assembly reusing all of the buissiness logic and keeping viwemodels where they belong (the WebUI project)

Hope this helps.

Best regards.

Comment: Noice! This is almost exactly how I do it except that my .Data, .Domain and .Services layers are all in their own projects / DLLs.

Comment: Right now I decide about splitting in projects depending on the solution size if it's "small" I keep it in a single project. I'm trying to get to a name space structure that's independent of whether I decide to split or not. You might want to take a look at: https://github.com/mvelosop/MicroFlow

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service architecture of your project , where all function and db queries are in this files and which you could using just by adding this code

```
 IOrderService<Order> service = new OrderEntityService();
```

and use it like

```
service.Create(Order) or service.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats strange to me is you're taking care and effort to layer out your app as much as possible, but you're still letting your MVC controller contain a lot of your logic. You're trying to share the objects and models, but the logic to add a new OrderEditViewModel is not shared, its stuck within that controller.

What I try and do is create a "helper" or "logic" class for each of my controllers. That logic or helper class is then injected into my controllers and wrapped in an interface. My controller can save, edit and remove items through my helper class, but has no knowledge of how its actually doing that.

I have then shared these logic classes along with the models to other projects, allowing a lot of code re-use. The problem is just ensuring that none of the "HTTP'ness" of the controllers sneaks into your logic classes, as these must be usable in a console or winforms application. So you have to be pretty strict and wrap a lot of things like HTTPSession or HTTPContext into interfaces that can then have non HTTP implementations..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I understand your situation and also tends to a DDD (Domain Driven Design) solution as @MystereMan suggests.

I have an approach that sepparates the "Models" in 3 categories:

1. ViewModels: Have all the information necessary to display content data in the UI
2. RequestModels: Have all the information necesssary to send data, post/get/etc.)
3. AutoBindModels: Have all the information that is injected my MVC binding model (cookies, sessions, etc..)

And the most important, for all that classes I use as DTO/POCO's, actually they have no UI dependent code just properties/calculated properties and could be easily in any other project to be referenced by an UI project.

You could also create a Controller class that act as a Service outside ASP.MVC project and extend or inject it in your MVC controller.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I never reuse (Edit)ViewModels objects (this is not entirely true, I often share one EditViewModel between Create and Update but not always).

I design my ViewModels for specific Views. Therefore, I don't have to compromise my ViewModels when the UI changes (it changes all the time).

I take this as far as creating two distinct ViewModels even if they are identical. I'm done refactoring shared ViewModels..

I would answer **yes** to your question.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

`OrderEditViewModel` and `OrderViewModel` are both 'ViewModels' end of the day. IMO, they may stay together in the same project even in your same 'ViewModels' folder. You may though create a sub folder under ViewModels for your 'EditViewModels'.

Now as you want to clean/tidy up the controller actions, you may want to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com). You are mapping domain entity and view models manually. That is a tiresome job. With AutoMapper you can do something like:

```
var customerInfo = Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel, CustomerInfo>(customerViewModel);
```

Comment: this doesn't talk about my requirement at all around then where to put your update logic?

Comment: @leora _"I am trying to figure out how to get as much code as possible outside the MVC project."_

That was probably my take. Anyway, thanks for encouraging me.

Comment: understand but the core part of the question is should these EditViewModel classes move over to the business side of the application or stay wiht the UI and if so where do data update logic go